# around advice and proceed call: aspectJ, how it works?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I've been trying to figure out what the `around` *advice* works in `AspectJ`.

It's not simple like the *before* and after *advice*. Could someone please give a brief introductory view of what the `around` advice does, and what is the purpose of the `proceed` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very informally, an `around` *advice* intercepts a given *joinpoint*, and can *inject* new behavior *before*, *after*, and *instead of* that *joinpoint*. The `proceed` is a special *feature* that allows the `around` *advice* to continue the execution of the `joinpoint`.

From the types of *advice* supported by AspectJ (*i.e.,* `before`, `after`, and `around`), the `around` *advice* is the only one allowed to *return* a value and/or use the `proceed`. This makes it possible for an `around` *advice* to execute several times the same *joinpoint*, or not executed it at all. Furthermore, you can even execute the intercepted *joinpoint* with a different context (*e.g.*, change the value of the method arguments). More details can be found [here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html).

Let us use some code as an example. Imagine a class named `Rectangle`:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private double width, height;

    public void setWidth(double w) {
           System.out.println("Set Width " + w);
           this.width = w;
    }
 
    public void setHeight(double h) {
           System.out.println("Set height " + h);
           this.height = h;
    }

    
    public double getWidth() {return this.width;}
    public double getHeight() {return this.height; }
}
```

and the methods of that class being called in:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle();
        s.setWidth(10);
        s.setHeight(2);
        double w =  s.getWidth();
        double h = s.getHeight()
        System.out.println("Width " + w + " Height " + h);
    }
}
```

If you run the code above, you will get the following output:

```
Set Width 10.0
Set Height 2.0
Width 10.0 Height 2.0
```

However, let us add some `around` *advices* into the mix:

```
 void around(double w) : call(public void  Rectangle.setWidth(double)) && args(w){
      System.out.println("Before setting width");
      proceed(w + 100);
      proceed(w + 100);
      System.out.println("After setting width");
 }
 
 double around() : call(public double  Rectangle.getHeight()){
        System.out.println("Before getting Height");
        double h = proceed();
        System.out.println("After getting Height");
        return h + 200;
 }

 void around(double w) : call(public void  Rectangle.setHeight(double)) && args(w){
        System.out.println("No Height setting");
  }
```

Now you will get the output:

```
Before setting width
Set Width 110.0
Set Width 110.0
After setting width
No Height setting
Before getting Height
After getting Height
Width 110.0 Height 200.0
```

So let us try to make sense out of that output, step-by-step, shall we?!. The first *advice*  will intercept the call to the method `public void  Rectangle.setWidth(double)` in the class `Rectangle`. And will:

1. add the statement `System.out.println("Before setting width");` before the call of that method;
2. execute the *joinpoint* twice (*i.e.,* call the method `setWidth` twice), modifying its original parameter from `w` to `w + 100`;
3. add the statement `System.out.println("After setting width");` after the call of that method.

Consequently, the original code is now equivalent to:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle();
        System.out.println("Before setting width");  // <--- new lines
        s.setWidth(10+100);
        s.setWidth(10+100);
        System.out.println("After setting width");   // <--- new lines
        s.setHeight(2);
        double w =  s.getWidth();
        double h = s.getHeight()
        System.out.println("Width " + w + " Height " + h);
    }
}
```

The second `around` *advice* will intercept the calls to the method `public double  Rectangle.getHeight()`, inject before and after those method calls the statements `System.out.println("Before getting Height");` and `System.out.println("After getting Height");`, respectively. Moreover, will add `200` to the value returned by `getHeight`. Hence,

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle();
        System.out.println("Before setting width"); 
        s.setWidth(10+100);
        s.setWidth(10+100);
        System.out.println("After setting width");  
        s.setHeight(2);
        double w =  s.getWidth();
        System.out.println("Before getting Height"); // <-- new lines
        double h = s.getHeight() + 200 // <-- new behaviour 
        System.out.println("After getting Height"); // <-- new lines
        System.out.println("Width " + w + " Height " + h); 

    }
}
```

Finally, the third `around` *advice* will *replace* the call to the method `public void Rectangle.setHeight(double)` by the statement `System.out.println("No Height setting");`. Consequently:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle s = new Rectangle();
        System.out.println("Before setting width"); 
        s.setWidth(10+100);
        s.setWidth(10+100);
        System.out.println("After setting width");
        System.out.println("No Height setting"); // <-- new line  
        double w =  s.getWidth();
        System.out.println("Before getting Height");
        double h = s.getHeight() + 200 // <-- new behaviour 
        System.out.println("After getting Height");
        System.out.println("Width " + w + " Height " + h); 

    }
}
```

This is just a small illustration of how the *advice* `around` works, does not mean that you should replicate the same what was done in this example, and does not accurately show how the *weaving* process happens under the hood.