# How to catch and suppress an Exception Thrown from a Java Class using Aspectj

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect

I want to handle this exception thrown from `Circle.getArea()` method using Aspectj.

**Shape.java**

```
    package Shapes;
    
    public class Circle {
        private double radius;
        public Circle(double radius) {
               this.radius = radius;
        }
        public double getPerimeter(){
               return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
        }
        public double getArea(){
            return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
        }
    }
```

**Rectangle.java**

```
    package Shapes;
    
    public class Rectangle {
        private double width, height;
        public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
             this.width = width;
             this.height = height;
        }
        public double getPerimeter() {
               return 2 * (this.width + this.height);
        }
        public double getArea() {
               return this.width * this.height;
        }
    }
```

**Circle.java**

```
    package Shapes;
    
    public class Circle {
        private double radius;
        public Circle(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
        public double getPerimeter() {
            return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
        }
        public double getArea() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Oops, I don't know how to calculate this :(");
        }
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
    package Shapes;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Shape s;
                s = (Shape) new Rectangle(2, 10);
                System.out.println("The area of " + s + " is " + s.getArea());
                
                s = (Shape) new Rectangle(-2, 10);
                System.out.println("The perimeter of " + s +" is " + s.getPerimeter());
                
                s = (Shape) new Circle(-2);
                System.out.println("The perimeter of " + s +" is " + s.getPerimeter());
                
                s = (Shape) new Circle(2);
                System.out.println("The area of " + s + " is " + s.getArea());
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    }
```

Resolve.aj

```
    package Shapes;
    
    privileged public aspect Resolve {
        declare parents: Rectangle implements Shape;
        declare parents: Circle implements Shape;
        
        public String Rectangle.getName(){
            return "Rectangle";
        }
        
        public String Circle.getName(){
            return "Circle";
        }
        
        public String Rectangle.toString(){
            return this.getName()+"("+this.width+","+this.height+")";
        }
        public String Circle.toString(){
            return this.getName()+"("+this.radius+")";
        }
        
    
        after() throwing(RuntimeException e) : execution(* Circle.*()){
            handleException();
        }   
    
        protected void handleException()
        {
            System.out.println("Error detected");
        }
    }
```

**The current output is:**

```
The area of Rectangle(2.0,10.0) is 20.0

The perimeter of Rectangle(-2.0,10.0) is 16.0

The perimeter of Circle(-2.0) is -12.566370614359172

Error detected

Error: Oops, I don't know how to calculate this :(
```

I want to avoid printing "Error: Oops, I don't know how to calculate this :(", and I need to get the real area of the circle object at the end.
But, I cannot change any .java file. All changes should be using Resolve.aj file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `around` *advice* instead of the *after*:

```
     Object around () : execution(* Circle.*()){
         try {
              return proceed();
         } 
         catch(Exception e) 
         {
            handleException();
         }
         return null;
    }
```

**Code output:**

```
The area of Rectangle(2.0,10.0) is 20.0
The perimeter of Rectangle(-2.0,10.0) is 16.0
The perimeter of Circle(-2.0) is -12.566370614359172
Error detected
The area of Circle(2.0) is 0.0
```

**Why are we using the around advice instead of the after?**

Very informally, an `around` *advice* intercepts a given *joinpoint*, and can *inject* new behavior *before*, *after*, and *instead of* that *joinpoint*. The `proceed` is a special *feature* that allows the `around` *advice* to continue the execution of the `joinpoint`.

From the types of *advice* supported by AspectJ (*i.e.,* `before`, `after`, and `around`), the `around` *advice* is the only one allowed to *return* a value and/or use the `proceed`. This makes it possible for an `around` *advice* to execute several times the same *joinpoint*, or not executed it at all. Furthermore, you can even execute the intercepted *joinpoint* with a different context (*e.g.*, change the value of the method arguments).

More information about how the advice and proceed works can be found on [this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254073/around-advice-and-proceed-call-aspectj-how-it-works/65254754#65254754).

Our `around` *advice* will intercept all the execution *joinpoint* of the methods from the class `Circle`, and will handle accordingly the exceptions thrown by those methods.